# Computer for specific job

Tags: graphics, ram, cpu

To be precise I will give as many details as possible.

I've been a mac user for over 3 years now, I loved it and I am still very found of OSX. As an operating system is insanely awesome.But hardware wise, I wanna move as far away from apple as possible.

This being said, you know I moved to Linux.

I am a web and android developer and I work from home, therefor I need to manage the workflow myself.As I was so used to OSX, it's hard to move to another UNIX based system, specially when support for the programs I use is not always on my side.

Anyways, I chose Ubuntu and it works great for my needs, but my PC is not that good, it's fairly decent but I feel like an upgrade is required, specially because I run a triple monitor setup and the video card seems to work hard quite a lot.

So, what I use the most: sublimetext, photoshop, chrome/mozzila, VPS connection, skype.That's pretty much it, but all those at the same time and chrome with at least 7-10 tabs open.

My current PC is:

- i3 4150
- 8GB RAM
- nVidia GTX 750 TI (2gb version)
- 120GB Adata SSD. (kinda low speeds, but enough for my needs)

The two things I must change at this PC are the power supply as it is a nJOy 450W that makes way too much noise and the motherboard because it's somewhat faulty -when I turn off the PC, 2 out 5 times it will come back on by itself and as far as I could see it's no bios settings or OS settings.

Now, what should I upgrade so that my PC will run Ubuntu perfectly?

Comment: Don't upgrade anything.

Comment: The motherboard could be fine. Some people report system restarts when they select 'shut down' from menus. Search thus forum to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is faster than mine, and probably faster than many of the one that people is using right now to read your question.

I'd only suggest you some improvements on your Window Manager, perhaps a different Desktop manager ([What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)), or a Tiling Window Manager such as i3WM (https://i3wm.org/) which will result in a faster experience, more concentration and less distraction.

But your computer is good. Just improve your system's performance by using the proper customization so that you feel everything is better.

BTW: You can find good alternatives to the most popular software, and excellent pieces of software useful to do the majority of the thins you do without need to run proprietary software. But if you insist on using that software, you can try PlayOnLinux or Wine to do so.

Ubuntu uses to come pre-installed with Unity, which is a resources demanding desktop environment, but you may experience a better performance by using, let's say: XFCE, LXDE, or even KDE. Just get the proper information on how to install and enjoy.

Good luck!

Comment: Indeed,I am already using playonlinux and wine, it does the job fairly well, minor bugs, nothing to be worried about.

THank you for the answer,it's awesome.I will be looking into the DEsktop manager options and see what I can go for.

THanks a lot for the answer again :)